# Making Transactional deletes in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data

I have an application that is using `Spring data'.

I want to ensure that either **both** deletions (code below) are carried out, or for a **rollback** to happen.

How can I ensure that `.delete()` methods shown below are `transactional`?

```
@Service
public class databaseService{

    //some code


  public void deleteRows(){

    carRepository.delete(car);
    personRepository.delete(person);

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the @Transactional annotation.

Comment: I have seen it when researching, Do I just add it to my method above? Can you please give an example

Comment: Yes you should just add it in the method above. It should usually be done at the service layer of your application which seems to be the case here. Be sure not to use nested transactions though, it leads to some weird behaviours in my experience.

Comment: Well sometimes a service calls another service. I've experienced some trouble when both of them were transactionnal, since the one calling wraps it's own transaction around the one being called, essentially ending up with nested transactions. Depending on the SGBD this can yield some funky results when you need to rollback.